# Mvvmcross 6.2.3 strange behavior of viewmodel navigation

Tags: mvvmcross

I'm playing with MVVMCROSS 6.2.3 and I have an issue with nested navigation in my XForms UWP app.

Here is a description:
VM1 navigate to VM2 and **VM1 is waiting for a result of VM2**!

VM2 navigate to VM3, VM2 does not need a result of VM3.
After navigation from VM2 to VM3 and VM1 is unexpectedly getting a null result.

```
public class MainViewModel : MvxViewModel
{
    public IMvxAsyncCommand GoToSecondPageCommand =>
        new MvxAsyncCommand(async () =>
        {
            var param = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "ButtonText", ButtonText } };

            var result = await navigationService.Navigate<SecondViewModel, Dictionary<string, string>, SecondViewModelResult>(param);
            var breakpoint = 1;


            //HERE IS THE ISSUE, result IS NULL because it fires immediately after Navigate<ThirdViewModel>()


        });

    public IMvxAsyncCommand BackCommand => new MvxAsyncCommand(async () =>
    {
        await navigationService.Close(this, new SecondViewModelResult { Result = "Back button clicked" });
    });
}

public class SecondViewModel : MvxViewModel<Dictionary<string, string>, SecondViewModelResult>
{
    public IMvxAsyncCommand GoToThirdPageCommand =>
        new MvxAsyncCommand(async () =>
        {
            var t = await navigationService.Navigate<ThirdViewModel>();
            var breakpoint = 2;
        });
}

public class ThirdViewModel : MvxViewModel
{
}
```

You could run it by yourself from my GitHub https://github.com/JTOne123/XamFormsMvxTemplate

This behavior was good in version 5.7 and **VM1 is waiting until VM2 return the result**.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please provide some code for context.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!, I've added the code and link to my github